# Stata: Replacing egen in a loop

Tags: stata

I am trying to count non-missing values subject to a varying `if` condition. And then take the `max` for each month.

```
gen xx1=.
gen xx2=.

forvalues i = 1/12{
bys state year month: replace xx1= 1 if month==`i' & no_monthsreport>=`i'
bys state year month: replace xx2= sum(!missing(xx1))
bys state year month: egen tot_xx3 =max(xx2)
}
```

I have noticed that the `egen` command cannot be `replace`d. So the loop doesn't work. I was wondering whether there is a way of doing this without creating more variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The immediate answer is that `egen` does not have a `replace` option, nor is there a `replace`-type command corresponding to `egen`. So you would need to `drop` or `rename` any previous result with the same variable name as that you want to use in an `egen` command.

In this problem, however, `egen` is not needed any way and the loop looks wrongly placed too. I don't understand what you want to do, but I think you want something more like

```
gen xx1 = .
forvalues i = 1/12 {
    replace xx1 = 1 if month == `i' & no_monthsreport >= `i'
} 
bys state year month: gen xx2 = sum(xx1)
bys state year month: gen tot_xx3 = xx2[_N]
```

Notice that

1. A framework of `by:` is not needed for the calculation of `xx1` as nothing depends on the surrounding group of observations.
2. The calculation of the running or cumulative sum of `xx1` can be done just once.
3. By construction `xx1` is either missing or 1. Hence `xx1` is not missing precisely when it is not 1. There is no need to fire up the `missing()` function and then negate it when you can count the 1s directly.
4. The maximum value of a running sum of 1s is just the last value. (Missings are ignored by `sum()`.)

Whether you want calculations to be done separately by `state`, `year` **and** `month` is up to you, but that choice is often a source of bugs.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
ssc install ereplace
ereplace xx1 = max(xx1)
```